# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType

Tags: android, okhttp

I am getting this error while changing my code from default `HTTPClient` to `OkHTTP`. Searched all through the web but it is not getting resolved.

I tried the same with `OkHTTP` library from [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and also with [dependency](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.squareup.okhttp%7Cokhttp%7C1.2.0%7Cjar)
 but still the error is same.

Please help me to resolve this.

***The Errors are:***

```
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
 doInBackground() 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):   at
 android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) 01-01 22:03:18.038:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) 01-01
 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):  at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 01-01 22:03:18.038:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1460): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
 com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType 01-01 22:03:18.038:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 com.kaverisoft.servicemanager.api.RemoteAPI.<clinit>(RemoteAPI.java:340)
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 com.kaverisoft.servicemanager.BusinessCodeActivity$ActivationCodeConfirmation.doInBackground(BusinessCodeActivity.java:314)
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 com.kaverisoft.servicemanager.BusinessCodeActivity$ActivationCodeConfirmation.doInBackground(BusinessCodeActivity.java:1)
 01-01 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 01-01 22:03:18.038:
 E/AndroidRuntime(1460):    at
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 01-01
 22:03:18.038: E/AndroidRuntime(1460):  ... 3 more
```

Comment: Tried clean & build?

Comment: @EugenPechanec - I tried, but still the same crash :(

Comment: Your link is to version 1.2.0. Did you mean 2.2.0?

Comment: @JakeWharton - I am using 2.2.0 jar from - http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: Left click your project, build path -> configure build path -> order and export. Is the relevant library checked for import?

Comment: @AshishTamrakar: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by making a Multidex application please see [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) link on how to make multidex application.