# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

In my project, I have used OkHttp(version 2.5.0) as my network request library. But few days ago, I tried Retrofit2 as part of my app's network request library, as you know, the new Retrofit2 library dependence on OkHttp(version 3.2.0).So here comes the problem that when my app runs on android phone whose android version under android 5.0 always causes crash(larger version works well and causes no crash), the crash stack information shows as below:

```java
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.comingx.athit.client.ServiceGenerator.<clinit>(ServiceGenerator.java:22)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.comingx.athit.ui.fragments.CircleNativeFragment.onViewCreated(CircleNativeFragment.java:105)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5348)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.comingx.athit.client.ServiceGenerator.<clinit>(ServiceGenerator.java:22)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.comingx.athit.ui.fragments.CircleNativeFragment.onViewCreated(CircleNativeFragment.java:105)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
04-15 21:28:51.185 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5348)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
04-15 21:28:51.186 17238-17238/com.comingx.athit W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

From the stack trace, I guess that OkHttp(version 3.2.0) has some conflicts with OkHttp(version 2.5.0). Below I will give my external library configuration:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
```

Hope anyone who knows the problem can give me a favor! Great thanks!

**Update 1:**
Here is my **ServiceGenerator.java** :

```java
package com.comingx.athit.client;

import com.comingx.athit.model.Constants;
import com.comingx.athit.model.modelmanager.ModelManagerSingleton;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class ServiceGenerator {
    private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(
            new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request request = chain.request()
                            .newBuilder().addHeader("Cookie", ModelManagerSingleton.getNative_cookie()).build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }
    ).build();
    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.V3.API_PREFIX)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <T> T createService(Class<T> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could paste the code in `com.comingx.athit.client.ServiceGenerator` ?

Comment: It looks like OkHttp 3 is designed to allow collocation with earlier OkHttp, as judged by its use of a different package name.  I'm inclined to guess, therefore, that either (1) you do not in fact have OkHttp 3 in your runtime classpath, or (2) the OkHttp 3 in your classpath is incomplete, or (3) `com.comingx.athit.client.ServiceGenerator`, whatever that is, wants a different, maybe earlier, version.

Comment: I think you can remove 2 lines `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'`

Comment: @BNK Additionally, I have used OkHttp2.5.0 to build some class so that I can use them more conveniently, so I just can not remove OkHttp2.5.0 for I should rewrite much old code in my project if I do remove it. But I tried to remove OkHttp3.2.0, and it does no work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger (1) I update my question as you can view my **ServiceGenerator.java**, I think the **ServiceGenerator** is not the reason. (2) I tried to remove OkHttp3.2.0 and saved OkHttp2.5.0, but still the earlier version does't work for the crash.

Comment: @srain I update my question and now you can view the **ServiceGenerator.java**

Comment: @wizChen, the problem is associated the initialization of `ServiceGenerator.httpClient`.  That initialization depends on class `okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder`, whose internal name is spelled `okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder`.  This class is documented in the OkHttp docs, but it is not found at runtime.  That leaves me still at my alternatives (1) and (2).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Maybe it's just the difference of the ART and Dalvik. Sadly I could't figure out a effective solution but change my latest code to OkHttp 2.5.0. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Hi your guys, I just solve the problem and post my answer below, thank you all :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, finally I find the problem and solve it. I viewed a similar problem  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738080/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-squareup-okhttp-mediatype#answer-36618157) and find that maybe the **64K Methods** could cause the problem, so I came to [official site](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)
to view **Building Apps with Over 64K Methods**. 
Now you should compile the multidex library in your build.gradle file:

```java
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

And don't forget to config your defaultConfig:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
}
```

And finally you can write a **BaseApplication** extends to **Application**, over write the **attachBaseContext(Context base)** method as follows:

```java
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Don't forget to add this to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true">
</application>
```

Comment: How do we solve this problem for a maven project could not initialize class okhttp3.OkHttpClient