# Exception in Okhttp network library in below lollipop devices

Tags: android

My application is working fine in Lollipop devices. However, I got error when using devices with API lower than Lollipop.

I am using Okhttp for network operations and Okhttp is giving following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder
     at okhttp3.HttpUrl.parse(HttpUrl.java:642)
     at okhttp3.Request$Builder.url(Request.java:140)
```

Network operation are not running in pre-Lollipop devices but works fine in Lollipop (or above).

I am using following code to call the web api

```
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
OkHttpClient copy = client.newBuilder().readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
Response response = copy.newCall(request).execute();
System.out.println("Response completed: " + response);
return  response.body().string();
```

Comment: Do you have multidexing enabled?

Comment: yes multidexing is enabled

Comment: what is the reason behind this , I have searched lot but failed to find any one solution

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this can be that the proguard obfuscated the okhttp code.

If you're using `proguard` , make sure you've added these rules to your `proguard-rules.pro` file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2230) :

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Annotation
-keep class okhttp3.** { ; }
-keep interface okhttp3.* { ; }
-dontwarn okhttp3.*
```

Comment: where do I make these changes ?

Comment: in the `proguard-rules.pro` file which is in the project root directory.

Comment: Okay I did some R and D on it , Do I need to put hash in front of these lines or not ?

Comment: hash is used to comment in proguard, so no you should not use.

Comment: Okay , thank you , could you also let me know what is this proguard file for ?

Comment: if the problem is still there after using these rules then check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649121/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-okhttp3-okhttpclientbuilder

Comment: yes you are right boss , the problem is still there

Comment: proguard is used to shrinke/optimize/obfuscate your java code to reduce the apk size, refer this for details : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Comment: implementing new link functionality

Comment: sure buddy ,let me go through it completely , then I will let you know the results

Comment: thanks @Ashish , I found the solution , I exchange Aplication class with MultiDexApplication and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this kind of error extend your application class with MultiDexApplication , this will remove the error .`

public class Globals extends MultiDexApplication {`