# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java2, okhttp

I'm finding the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649121/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-okhttp3-okhttpclientbuilder) and tried with solution specified but still i'm getting the same error as below

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/OkHttpClient$Builder;

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "path" ]]
```

my gradle's is like

```
compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.4.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0' 
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'    


compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
```

I have my application classes which extends MultidexApplication.

Comment: Did you try to clean/rebuild/restart android studio?

Comment: i tried clean and rebuild dint tried with restarting android studio, will it be helping..

Comment: I dont know. Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Vucko dint helped

Answer (score -3):

Update your gradle file with this

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
}
```